# Apache CentOS 7 403 Forbidden Anyone?

Tags: centos, permissions, apache-2.4, forbidden

I am trying to setup a situation where I can FTP to my Linux CentOS 7 server and update the web site files from my Windows 7 system.  At this point I can FTP to my user's folder using vsftp (/home/robert) and Apache seems to work for the default web site (/var/www/html).  I created a virtual host for port 8080 and if I point it to /var/www/8080/public_html it works fine but as soon as I point it to /home/robert/public_html it comes back with 403 Forbidden. You don't have permission to access / on this server.
The apache error log shows

```
[Wed Mar 18 16:12:27.546621 2015] [core:error]
[pid 21204] (13)Permission denied: [client 192.168.1.66:57090]
AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/robert')
because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

The apache conf file (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf) has this entry for Virtual Host

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080

# Virtual Hosts
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName 192.168.1.10:8080
#   DocumentRoot /var/www/8080/public_html
    DocumentRoot /home/robert/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

The permissions for /home/robert/public_html/index.html are below

```
drwxr-xr-x.   7 root root   66 Mar  9 17:16 home
dr-x---r-x. 15 robert robert 4096 Mar 16 22:51 robert
drwxr-xr-x. 2 robert robert   23 Mar 17 23:28 public_html
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 robert robert 332 Mar 17 23:28 index.html
```

This seems like a permissions issue but I am unclear how to proceed.  Do I need to add apache user to my robert individual group?  Is selinux doing something here?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

**UPDATED:**  ok it appears to me that all web sites are supposed to be located under the /var/www/ folder.  It seems selinux wants it that way.  So how do I remotely FTP and access (read/write) the web site files??? Let's say I want user robert to FTP to /var/www/testweb and be able to read/write the files there.  How is that accomplished???

**UPDATED:** I looked at the answer posted and ran the three commands below

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs on
setsebool -P ftp_home_dir on
restorecon -r -v /home
```

Looks like it did something but the result is the same.  I can FTP to user folder still but web site does not show up...403 error.

**UPDATED:** I also tried to run the following command however it errored out on all files

Command I ran

```
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_t /home/robert/public_html
```

Error I received

```
chcon: failed to change context of ‘index.html’ to ‘unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_t:s0’: Permission denied
```

I also turned selinux off using setenforce 0 but I still got 403. 
Advice appreciated...thank you.

Comment: Is this a common issue? Anyone out there??

Comment: I was almost sure it was a SELinux problem, but as you even tried disabling it I guess we have to look elsewhere... did you check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for messages after doing `setenforce 0`? try also to `su` to the account apache runs on to see if you can access the file (e.g. `su apache -s /bin/sh -c 'cat /home/robert/public_html/index.html'`)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me.  I appreciate it.
audit log doesn't show anything wrong in my opinion. When I su apache -s /bin/bash and then cat /home/robert/public_html/index.html it says Permission denied. The permissions are listed above.  What should they be???

Comment: Oh my word I'm so excited!!!! I set permissions on /home/robert to 777 and it worked!!!!  I then stepped it back to 577 and it worked! I then put it to 505 and it still worked!!! I changed it to 500 and I received 403 error.  So it looks like /home/robert needs to be 505 for Apache.  However now I cannot connect to FTP.  I guess my overall question remains....how can I host multiple web sites and FTP to them to update them?

Comment: If I setenforce 0 then FTP does work, but I would like to use selinux.  Also I did setsebool -P ftp_home_dir=1 but FTP still doesn't work.  Still so confused but hopeful.  =)

Comment: check the user and group name /etc/httpd/http.conf. It should be your working user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  Apache was working but the last command that made ftp work while still having selinux running was

```
setsebool -P ftpd_full_access on
```

Once I set that then FTP worked as it should.  So now I can FTP from my Windows 7 machine, update, publish change my web site files and Apache happily delivers the content.  Wow...that took days to solve.  Crazy.  I setup another user just to test and it all works just fine.